# service virtualization/mocking using QAF

Tags: web-services, mocking, qaf, service-virtualization

Does QAF support mocking/virtualization of service endpoint and request/response ?

Using QAF WSstep class we can invoke live url or we can register local endpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

While using QAF, you can use different mocking frameworks for service virtualization. Below are few of them:

- [MockServer](https://www.mock-server.com/)
- [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/)
- [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/)

Comment: I have explore WireMock which use Junit framework, however QAF support TestNG, it seems compatibility issue with different tool. I feel mocking tool which support testng is more suitable with QAF, please suggest.